# Pinia state as function parameter

Tags: vuejs3

I have a pinia store in my Vue3 application. Here is the store definition:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios';


export const useMapperStore = defineStore('mapper', {
    state: () => ({ mapper: {} }),
    getters: {
        getMapper: (state) => state.mapper,
    },
    actions: {
        fetchMapper() {
            axios.get(import.meta.env.VITE_JSON_MAPPER)
            .then(response => {
                this.mapper = response.data;
            })
        },
        getMap(){
            return this.mapper;
        }
    },
})
```

When I use the store inside my Vue component, it's works fine, for example

```
const wil_prov = this.mapperStore.mapper[prov] ?? null;
const wil_kab = this.mapperStore.mapper[city] ?? null;

// this is not working
generateBreadcrumbsLinks(this.$route.params, this.mapperStore).then(slug => {
    this.breadcrumbs = slug;
});
```

In the above code snippet, `wil_prov` and `wil_kab` has expected value. However when passing the store to function `generateBreadcrumbsLinks`, the `mapperStore.mapper` become its initial value, which is `{}`.

Comment: What is happening inside generateBreadcrumbsLinks? Why not import and initiliaze the store inside that function?